# Import data from web in MS EXCEL (web page published from Google Spreadsheet), but preserve line feeds

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any solution to preserve line feeds in Microsoft Excel when we import data from a webpage which is published Google Spreadsheet..

I have two or more lines in a single cell in Google Spreadsheet and this spreadsheet is published, here is the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AmMTqpzD9YRndG1IdEhpUWlUNndHbkZFUVREbHRNTFE&output=html

So now, as you can see the data in Cell A2 has more than one line and when I import this published spreadsheet in MS Excel it puts this single cell data into multiple rows, which I want to remain in a single cell as it is in Google Spreadsheet..

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the import result of your sample are really bad.

But how did you create those multiline cellss ? I tried the same and it works fine !
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Aj_YidytSKgidFZuTGwzdkZRWDYydXpWbTJNTmJYbkE&single=true&gid=0&output=html

I used Ctrl+Enter to create the new lines, and option File, Publish to the web, HTML, to get te link above. (wording may be slightly different, my version is in french)